# Python:- If i want to make an android app to run in background even if the screen is locked. What permission do i need for that from android?

Tags: android, python, android-fragments, kivy, buildozer

I made an app which detects shaking of an app but the app works only if the phone is unlocked and running.But when i run the app in Background then it do not recognize shake, That means app not working in background, what permission we need to make any app run in background in android and what permission we need to make the app run when phone is locked?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated than just a permission. You'll need to register a wakelock in your application. A wakelock tells the Android OS not to shut down your application when your device goes to sleep.

Here's the official Android documentation on wakelocks: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

You probably want the section titled "Keeping the CPU on"

Comment: Thankyou very much. But is there anything else that can run my apps in background too when i press home button?

Comment: In android, long-running background processes are usually run by services. The documentation is here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

The standard format is to have a service running in the background listening for events. You would then use a Broadcast receiver in your main application to communicate with your service